# Is there a way to see my server's mediawiki version using the terminal?

Tags: server, 18.04, mediawiki

So I was following a guide for upgrading MediaWiki. I want to know how can I check my installed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit `Special:Version`, or fetch the equivalent API if you really want to use it from the terminal. E.g.

```
curl -s 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&format=json' | jq '.query.general.generator'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, you can use a one-liner like this to find out:

```bash
grep -E 'wgVersion|MW_VERSION' /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/{DefaultSettings,Defines}.php
```

Depending on the Mediawiki version, it is defined in either `includes/DefaultSettings.php` or in `includes/Defines.php`.

- `includes/Defines.php` contains the definition of the `MW_VERSION` constant since version 1.31.
  For example:
  `define( 'MW_VERSION', '1.35.8' );`
- `includes/DefaultSettings.php` contains the `$wgVersion` variable definition for older versions, up to around version 1.30.
  For example:
  `$wgVersion = '1.19.24';` or
  `$wgVersion = '1.29.3';`